# Connecting address points to nearest part of a road network that has matching street name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, spatial-analyst, geoprocessing, proximity

In ArcGIS Pro (or ArcMap), using built-in Esri geoprocessing tools, how can I create connection lines between address points and the nearest part of a road segment *with a matching street name* (e.g. '*fishbones*')?

There are two Esri tools that come close:

- **Generate Origin-Destination Links** (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/generate-origin-destination-links.htm). This tool allows user to condition the analysis on a matching field name (road name), but it matches the point geometry to the line *centroid* instead of the nearest part of the line segment.
- **Near** and **Generate Near Table** (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm and https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm). These tools allow a user to ultimately connect a point to the nearest portion of a line, but they do not allow the user to condition the analysis on matching attributes between the two input feature classes.

NOTE: I have already successfully generated fishbones using *geocoded* (interpolated) connection points on the road centerline network and I'm not interested in methods for this. I specifically want to see a connection between the address point and the nearest part of a line segment (with matching name).

Comment: Does this article provide your required output? https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011815

Comment: Nope. That article describes a process that uses the "Near" tool (in the Proximity Analysis toolbox), which I mentioned in my question does not allow the user to condition the process on a matching road name.

Comment: I think you should decide whether you wish to ask about the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap GUI in this particular question. If asking about ArcPy or Python please include a code snippet that illustrates what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck.

Comment: Use Generate Near table with large number of candidates. Remove no matches in regards of street names. Delete identical for point FID.

Comment: Thanks @FelixIP! Although it's still a bit cumbersome, it's the type of answer I was looking for. If you want to post it as an answer, I'd accept it. If you don't I'll use the answer-it-myself function. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@FelixIP](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/34531/felixip) commented a reasonable answer to this question so I'm expanding on it and posting it as the answer here:

1. Use the "[Generate Near Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm)" tool to match to *multiple* nearby features. For matching address points to the road segments, 3 candidates would likely be sufficient, but 4 or 5 candidates would ensure the least amount of manual review.

   [image]

   This will result in an output table with many extra, duplicate, and mismatched near features.
2. Using the `[IN_FID]` and `[NEAR_FID]` fields, join back to the input tables. For simplicity, it may be easiest to add fields to the near table (something like `[IN_ATT]` and `[NEAR_ATT]` to calculate the input and near attributes). Select and delete any rows where the desired attributes did *not* match.
3. Analyze the remaining records for duplicate `IN_FID`; query/sort/select to keep only the nearest match, deleting the more distant duplicates.